# Spring Hibernate project doesn't works

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I created a Spring + Hibernate project but does not work.Where am I doing wrong?
Why do I get error when I write sessionfactory.getCurrentSession? I always have to write sessionfactory.openSession .This is my second project using hibernate. In the first project I used jpa annotation in the class Student, but now I have created a file student.hbm.xml

Error code

```
ott 07, 2014 11:10:21 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
Informazioni: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@c5eb8a: startup date [Tue Oct 07 11:10:21 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
ott 07, 2014 11:10:21 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
Informazioni: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [springConfig.xml]
ott 07, 2014 11:10:22 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
ott 07, 2014 11:10:22 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
ott 07, 2014 11:10:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ott 07, 2014 11:10:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ott 07, 2014 11:10:24 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ott 07, 2014 11:10:24 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ott 07, 2014 11:10:24 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
ott 07, 2014 11:10:25 AM org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
Informazioni: Using DataSource [org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@1a3a7f7] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [coreservlets.StudentDAOImpl] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
at coreservlets.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)
```

Student.java

```
package coreservlets;

public class Student {

private Integer id;

private String name;

private Integer age;

public Integer getId(){return id;}//getId

public void setId(Integer id){this.id=id;}//setId

public String getName(){return name;}//getName

public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}//setName

public Integer getAge(){return age;}//getAge

public void setAge(Integer age){this.age=age;}//setAge

}//Student
```

StudentDAO.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public interface StudentDAO {

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory);

public void create(String name,Integer age);

}//StudentDAO
```

StudentDAOImpl.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
}//setSessionFactory

@Transactional
public void create(String name,Integer age){
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Student student=new Student();
    student.setName(name);
    student.setAge(age);
    session.persist(student);
}//create

}//StudentDAOImpl
```

MainApp.java

```
package coreservlets;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springConfig.xml");

    StudentDAOImpl student=(StudentDAOImpl)context.getBean(StudentDAOImpl.class);

    student.create("John", new Integer(33));

}//main

}//MainApp
```

springConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:annotation-config/>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_hibernate"/>
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="password"/>
  <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
  <property name="maxTotal" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>student.hbm.xml </value>
    </list>
</property>
<property name="annotatedClasses">
  <list>
    <value>coreservlets.Student</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
    </props>
</property>

</bean>

</beans>
```

student.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="coreservlets">
<class name="Student" table="student">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" />
    <property name="age" column="age" />
</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

sql code

```
create table student
(
id integer not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20) not null,
age integer not null,
primary key(id)
);
```

Comment: Where the bean StudentDAOImpl definition in your xml? <bean id="StudentDAOImpl" class="coreservlets.StudentDAOImpl" />

Comment: I used @Autowired annotation in StudentDaoImpl and <context:annotation-config/> in springConfig.xml

Comment: @Autowired StudentDAO studentDAO; in main class, but not a good practice to use this in static method

Comment: You have used @Autowired in your StudentDAOImpl on sessionFactory not on your class.

Comment: @Autowired is on setSessionFactory method..if i move it on sessionFactory attribute i have the same error

Comment: Why are you expecting a session to already be present? I can't see anything in the code that implies a session would already be present by the time you reach your DAO. I would recommend writing your DAO using a Spring Hibernate callback, with a doInHibernate method, which should create the session for you if it does not exist. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977121/advantages-of-using-hibernate-callback

Comment: If i remove @Autowired annonation and i add bean studentDAOImpl in springConfig.xml i have this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10 cannot be cast to coreservlets.StudentDAOImpl
 at coreservlets.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:12)

Comment: How can i solve my problem??

Comment: if u have @autoWired bean class then where is the registration into the xml file?

Comment: @Autowired annotation in StudentDaoImpl and <context:annotation-config/> in springConfig.xml..Is this sufficient?

Comment: Look this image: http://imgur.com/SW4FQ1Q

I have two red simbol.Why?
The first: advises coreservlets.StudentDAOImpl.create(String,Integer)
The second: advised by 
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface :

```
public interface StudentDAO {

}
```

Class which implements interface `StudentDAO`:

```
@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

}
```

To autowire `StudentDAOImpl` class, you have to put `@Autowired` annotation on interface name, your class:

```
@Autowired
private StudentDAO studentDAO;
```

also you have to take care of configuration, like for component scanning you have to add following line in your spring configuration file. Put
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.dao"/>` in spring configuration xml  and change `com.org.dao` to your package name where dao files placed in application.